# UITextField showing multiline text in Objective C iOS , Xcode 10.2, iOS 13

Tags: uitextfield, ios13, xcode10.2

i am assigning URL to textfield but it showing in multi line. But when i assign simple text work fine.

Here is the code.

`_searchTF.text = @"asdfasdfaa asdfas asdfasdfasfasdf";` it work fine.

`_searchTF.text = @"https://gmailjhasdfhkajhdfahsdfkhaskdfhashdf.com";` showing in multi line

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is beta version issue please update `os` on latest.